# Max Date and Concatenate on separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone help me with a solution to this problem? I need to do two things with my data.

1. I need to get the max date
2. I need to concatenate the values in the Proj_Use column

My data looks like this:

```
Report_Date  |  Program  |  Project  |  Proj_Mgr  |  Region  |  Proj_Use

6/5/2017  |  PG1  |  Prj01  |  Anne  |  East  |  PU1

6/4/2017  |  PG1  |  Prj01  |  Anne  |  East  |  PU2

6/3/2017  |  PG1  |  Prj01  |  Anne  |  East  |  PU3

6/5/2017  |  PG2  |  Prj02  |  Monica  |  West  | PU4

6/4/2017  |  PG2  |  Prj02  |  Monica  |  West  |  PU5

6/3/2017  |  PG2  |  Prj02  |  Monica  |  West  |  PU6
```

My results should look like this:

```
Report_Date Program Project Proj_MgrRegion  Proj_Use

6/5/2017 | PG1 | Prj01 | Anne | East | PU1, PU2, PU3

6/5/2017 | PG2 | Prj02 | Monica | West | PU4, PU5, PU6
```

I can get the max date by using the following code:

```
    SELECT   t.[Report_Date]
        ,t.[Program]
        ,t.[Project]
        ,t.[Proj_Mgr]
        ,t.[Region]
        ,t.[Proj_Use]
    FROM project_table t
    JOIN
    (SELECT MAX([Report_Date]) as [Report Date], [Program]
        FROM project_table
        GROUP BY [Program]) max
        ON t.[Report_Date] = max.[Report Date]
        AND t.[Program] = max.[Program]
```

I searched on the forum for a way to concatenate and found the group_concat method for sql server. I've tried to add that to the code and came up with this:

```
    SELECT   t.[Report_Date]
        ,t.[Program]
        ,t.[Project]
        ,t.[Proj_Mgr]
        ,t.[Region]
        ,STUFF ((
            SELECT ',' + t.[Proj_Use]
                FROM project_table
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1, '') AS [Project Use]
    FROM project_table t
    JOIN
    (SELECT MAX([Report_Date]) as [Report Date], [Program]
        FROM project_table
        GROUP BY [Program]) max
        ON t.[Report_Date] = max.[Report Date]
        AND t.[Program] = max.[Program]
```

When I tried to run this using my real data the query ran for over 20 minutes without producing results.

Can anyone let me know if I've structured this query correctly or if there is a better way to get the results I'm looking for?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big thing you are missing is the `where` clause inside your subquery.

Using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

Try this:

```
select
    ReportDate = max(t.Report_Date)
  , t.Program
  , t.Project
  , t.Proj_Mgr
  , t.Region
  , [Project_Use] = stuff((
   select ',' + i.Proj_Use
   from project_table i
   where i.Program = t.Program
     and i.Project = t.Project
     and i.Proj_Mgr = t.Proj_Mgr
     and i.Region = t.Region
   for xml path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
   , 1, 1, '') 
from project_table t
group by t.Program, t.Project, t.Proj_Mgr, t.Region
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SEBKZD40038

returns:

```
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
| ReportDate | Program | Project | Proj_Mgr | Region | Project_Use |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2017-06-04 | pg1     | Prj01   | Anne     | East   | pu1,pu2,pu3 |
| 2017-06-04 | pg2     | Prj02   | Monica   | West   | pu4,pu5,pu6 |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: This worked for me. I do want to point out for anyone looking at the solution that you included an extra closing ) in the FOR XML statement. To make it work it should look like this:                                                   for xml path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  Also thanks for the links to the additional information. Very helpful.

Comment: @matt Whoops! at least it was correct in the demo. Fixed the typo in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting something like this:

```
SELECT pt.*,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + pt2.[Proj_Use]
              FROM project_table pt2
              WHERE pt2.Program = pt.Program
              ORDER BY pt2.[Report Date]
              FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS [Projects Used]
FROM (SELECT pt.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Program ORDER BY [Report Date] DESC) as seqnum
      FROM project_table t
     ) pt
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

At a minimum, your subquery to do the concatenation doesn't have a correlation clause to the outer query (so the intermediate string is likely to be very long).  There are probably other issues as well.